# How to recover the spl-token authority changed?

Tags: solana

The hacker changed the authority address
how do we now change the authority address back? And can we burn the tokens that were minted by the hacker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not the owner / authority of the token account, you cannot do anything else with it.

If you want to burn token in an account you own, you can use the CLI's `burn` command:

```
spl-token burn <ACCOUNT_ADDRESS_IN_BASE_58> <AMOUNT>
```

More information about burning at https://spl.solana.com/token#burning